# Digital Asset Management system for ~50TB of images/videos?

Tags: digital-asset-management

I am looking for a [Digital Asset Management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_asset_management) system.

It will contain media files, especially for the photographers and artists:

- All image formats
- Videos
- Probably SWF files
- Some document types

The data will be rather big (tens of terabytes). I am also thinking about cloud storage as we are not sure what kind of server configuration we require.

Comment: This question is unanswerable. You *only* give us one vague requirement ('huge data'). Edit your question and give numbers.

Comment: What kind of assets do you want to store? Images? Videos? Documents? Software? Opaque binaries? As Jan asked: How many assets? Thousands? Millions? Billions? And what total size? Terabytes? Petabytes?

Comment: @JanDoggen well the users we are looking t its Thousand users but we probably guessing they will upload huge files because we are giving more space (not yet decided)

Comment: @NicolasRaoul we are planing for the media files especially for the photographer and artists so we are looking at all image formats and videos probably SWF files along with document types.

Comment: @SandyUgale: How many terabytes/petabytes?

Comment: I fixed the question, because in its current shape it would have got closed. I said ~50TB but feel free to say if it is more/less. I also removed the DB part as you are looking for a DAM rather than only a DB (DAM includes a DB). Also, what is your budget? Do you need professional support?

Answer (score 2):

Alfresco is perfect for [Digital Asset Management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_asset_management):

- Web preview for images, videos, ZIPs, PDFs, and many other formats
- Gallery/filstrip view
- Content rules
- Image transformations
- Metadata extraction
- Custom metadata
- Workflows
- CMIS compatible
- And of course all of the features of an [Enterprise Content Management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise%20Content%20Management) product

It is free and open source.

It features a web asset management user interface, but it is also a convenient platform to build your own custom application on, if needed.

Comment: ..it sounds nice and I will review it in more details but here I am planing to ground up the solution at first level then we probably think about open source solution.